# Numpy: How to resize an random array using another array as template

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 5x5 array like this:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I also have a 3x3 array like this:

```
array([[ 1.,  0., 1.],
       [ 0.,  1., 0.]])
```

I'd like to merge the 3x3 array into the 5x5 array so that it looks like:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Similarly, I maybe have other arrays with various dimensions (25, 25), (15, 13), (2, 8), etc. What is the best way to use a 5x5 array of zeros as a template to merge other arrays into it?

For example, suppose my "template" array is zeroes((5, 5)). I have another array that is ones((12, 12)). I would like to resize the ones((12, 12)) such that it's new size will be 5x5. Regarding the "extra" rows/columns: the last 7 rows and the last 7 columns should be ignored.

Is there a built in numpy method that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the shape of second array then use `indexing` to apply the second array to first one :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
...        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> b=np.array([[ 1.,  0., 1.],
...           [ 0.,  1., 0.]])

>>> i,j=b.shape
>>> a[:i,:j]=b
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

But when the array `b` is bigger than `a` as you want to replace the `a`'s elements with elements of `b` you just can split the `b` array with shape of `a` then assign to `a`:

```
>>> b=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])

>>> i,j=a.shape
>>> a=b[:i,:j]
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]])
```

Comment: That works if array 'b' is equal or smaller than 'a'. But if 'b' is a larger array, I get an error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10) into shape (5,5)

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using my own solution posted below. But I will accept your answer as it helped to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
def reshape_array(orig_array):
    max_x = 5
    max_y = 5
    rows, cols = orig_array.shape
    if rows < max_x:
        new_row_len = max_x - rows
    elif rows >= max_x:
        new_row_len = 0
    if cols < max_y:
        new_col_len = max_y - cols
    elif cols >= max_y:
        new_col_len = 0
    new_x = np.zeros((new_row_len, cols))
    new_y = np.zeros((max_y, new_col_len))

    result = np.copy(orig_array)
    result = np.delete(result, np.s_[max_y:], axis=1)
    result = np.delete(result, np.s_[max_x:], axis=0)

    if not len(new_x) == 0:
        result = np.append(result, new_x, axis=0)
    if not len(new_y) == 0:
        result = np.append(result, new_y, axis=1)
    return result
```

I tested the following arrays successfully with reshape_array()

```
a = np.ones((3, 3))
b = np.ones((5, 5))
c = np.ones((2, 4))
d = np.ones((10, 10))
```